# In Jenkins pipeline, How can I set a parameter's value from a script caculating?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am testing in declarative pipeline. (if you have idea in scriped pipeline, that is welcome too.)
We know in pipeline, we can set parameter as below:

```
parameters {
    string(name: "parametera", defaultValue : "a value", description: "description a")}
```

I wannt it to be a value by script executing, like below :

```
sh("echo ${JOB_NAME} | cut -d '_' -f 3")
```

something like below

```
parameters {
    string(name: "parametera", defaultValue : sh("echo ${JOB_NAME} | cut -d '_' -f 3"), description: "description a")}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work, it will get synax error, like below.

```
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {name=parametera, defaultValue={name=sh, args={<anonymous>=echo mlp_loyalty-booster-center_dev_DEV-debugging | cut -d '_' -f 3}}, description=description a} for hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition
```

How can I do this, any idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a kind of a chicken-and-egg problem.

To run your job (Groovy code), parameters must be set before the code runs. However, you want to set the parameters by running Groovy code. There's a contradiction there.

You may fool the system by having a scripted pipeline before a declarative one, e.g. like this:

```
def part3 = null
println "The value of part3 before scripted pipeline is ${part3}"

node('master') {
    stage('Calculate part3') {
        println "The value of part3 before calculation is ${part3}"
        part3 = sh returnStdout: true, script: "echo ${JOB_NAME} | cut -d '_' -f 3"
        println "The value of part3 after calculation is ${part3}"
    }
}

println "The value of part3 after scripted pipeline is ${part3}"

pipeline {
    parameters {
        string(name: "parametera", defaultValue : part3, description: "description a")}
...
}
```

This will not work in all cases, specifically first run of your pipeline will use `null`, and subsequent runs will use the result of a previous run (to get out of chicken-and-egg problem outlined above). This may or may not be what you want. If you have a multi-branch configuration, the previous run on a specific branch is good enough as branches do not change between the runs.

Comment: Thanks, It almost work.  Depend on your solution, I can see the parameter "part3" in job configuration.  But very strange, when I click 'build with parameters', I can not see the parameter 'part3' .  Do you know the possible reason ?

Comment: And I have another strange thing. Before I tried your answer, I add a script {} in my decalration pipeline's Prepare stage.  the script is something like this :   myJob.addProperty(new ParametersDefinitionProperty(new StringParameterDefinition("action", "Build", "StringProp build Description")));  After this scripte I tried to access the new parameter "action", always get null. 

After I tried your answer added related content you mentioned ,  So magical, that I can get the value of "action".  Do you have any idea  what cased this magical thing ？